# How to access parent Activity View in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an `ActionBarActivity` and fragment. I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` that provides fragment to my app. My question How can I access parent Activity View in Fragment ??

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can use

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewid);
```

Quoting docs

> Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with
>   getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the
>   activity layout

Comment: Works, but I would use an interface to communicate with the activity or something like that.

Comment: your welcome to use the interface way also. But that is for communicating with activity

Comment: Yep who knows what the state is going to be, hacky I know but I have lunch to eat.

Comment: Cool, just you would need to check if Fragment is added by isAdded() to avoid crash if activity is not attached yet.

Comment: @Raghunandan. Doesn't work if I rotate the device. That time the view becomes null and i get a NPE

Comment: always get access from last fragment if I try to access from first or second fragment

Comment: Android docs are written in a very stupid way. Docs quoted as `Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout` yet Android Studio warning reads as `getActivity() may be null`

Comment: @FARID feel free to file a issue with google at android issues tracker. The docs might be updated. the warning is a lint warning. getactivity can be null if you try to access it even before the fragment is attached to the activity.

Comment: for Kotlin 
val view = activity!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.view)

Comment: Can we use the activity view reference in fragment xml ?

Comment: you can refer to a activity view in fragment

Comment: I ended up using
`final FloatingActionButton fab = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);`

Comment: @SteveGelman yes you can use requireActivity() or requireContexgt(). for more info and when to use what https://medium.com/android-news/the-requireactivity-and-requirecontext-example-1c089ce11a3a

Answer (score 9):

At first, create a view like this:

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewid);
```

Then convert it to any view that you need like this:

```
 if( view instanceof EditText ) {
            editText = (EditText) view;
            editText.setText("edittext");
            //Do your stuff
        }
```

or

```
if( view instanceof TextView ) {
  TextView textView = (TextView) view;
  //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9):

> In Kotlin it is very easy to access parent Activity View in Fragment

```
activity!!.textview.setText("String")
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are using findViewById<>() from activity, it wont work if you call it from fragment. You need to assign the view to variable. Here is my case

> This doesn't work

```kotlin
class MainActivity{

    fun onCreate(...){
        //works
        setMyText("Set from mainActivity")
    }

    fun setMyText(s: String){
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myText).text = s
    }
}
________________________________________________________________

class ProfileFragment{
    ...

    fun fetchData(){
        // doesn't work
        (activity as MainActivity).setMyText("Set from profileFragment")
    }
}
```

> This works

```kotlin
class MainActivity{

    private lateinit var myText: TextView

    fun onCreate(...){
        myText = findViewById(R.id.myText)

        // works
        setMyText("Set from mainActivity")
    }

    fun setMyText(s: String){
        myText.text = s
    }
}
________________________________________________________________

class ProfileFragment{
    ...

    fun fetchData(){
        // works
        (activity as MainActivity).setMyText("Set from profileFragment")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using kotlin then you can use this syntax

```
val view= requireActivity().findViewById<YourVIEW>(R.id.view_id)
```