# Fragment layout with FAB conflict with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Im using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/search?q=materialdrawer) with a `MainDrawerActivity` where I replace each fragment inside *container* `FrameLayout` based on selected item, but I want to add a FAB (just for this fragment) that interacts with `CoordinatorLayout` so it can handle cool animations.

MainDrawer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
      android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How I replace each fragment:

```
try {
  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FeedFragment()).commit()
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
  Timber.i(e, "Fragment is still there.")
}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:listitem="@layout/feed_item" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_little"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

But as result the FAB button is behind bottom bar:

[image: Sample]

Im trying setting the coordinator layout attribues (`layout_anchor` and those) to match the main layout ids but it is not working...
why?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix it ?

Comment: Yeah, you need to have the FAB in the main layout, should be direct child of coordinator layout to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Floating Action Button within the Activity - currently the Fragment's container is considered the parent.

FAB should be a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: I dont want to do that bc of events, I will have to call onFabButton on Fragments

Comment: your FloatingActionButton can be inflated / constructed beyond your Fragment. So long as you reference the Context which the FAB resides in - you can maintain the same functionality. In your fragment, create a member variable `FloatingActionButton mFAB;` and initialize it within onCreateView: `mFAB = (FloatingActionButton) container.findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);`

Comment: Doesn't work to find `(FloatingActionButton) container.findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);` in onCreateView. It is just the fragment container, not the activity layout.

Comment: The best way how to obtain fab from an activity is to initialize fab inside `onActivityCreated`. It can be done using `requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab)`; (solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22883607/9317258) answer). It works also for example inside Fragment's onCreate but only until you rotate your screen. (Fragment's onCreate is called before Activity's onCreate)